# In Angular how do I $eval() a function and pass the element to parent function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, eval

**Question:** 
How can I get `var trapfocus()` inside `ParentCtrl` to `console.log(el)` from the approrate element properly ?

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" modaltab="trapfocus($event)"></div>   
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  .directive('modaltab', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                if(event.which === 9) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.$eval(attrs.modaltab, {'event': event});
                    });
            });
        };
    })
```

**Parent Ctrl**

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', function(){ 
   var trapfocus = function(evt, el){console.log(el)};
   $scope.tabs = [1,2,3,4];

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `$eval`. Declare this attribute on the scope of the directive:

```
scope: {
   modaltab: "&"
}
```

Then, invoke it like so from the link function:

```
modaltab({'$event': event});
```